# VPN becomes unavailable when using 3G dongle on OSX

Tags: macos, vpn, 3g

I have VPN configured using Mac's native vpn support. It is working when I am using WiFi or ethernet connection but VPN becomes unavailable (drop-down menu says "VPN is not configured") when I'm using a 3G dial-up dongle.

When I open Network Prefrences, the location is set to Mobile Broadband and the VPN entries are not listed at all.

When I select Location: automatic the Network Preferences window becomes very sluggish,but shows all VPN entries. I then  hit connect on the VPN and nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

After further investigation, it appears that the 3G connection always switches to a new location - "Mobile Boradband" and that VPN connections are pinned to one location only - the one where they were created. So, the only solution is to re-create the connection in the Mobile Broadband location.

I used  export/import feature to save myself the typing.